# i have a variable which i want to share its values with all my controllers - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a variable that is **$data1**, i want to share the value of $data1 with all my controllers and use it

in my >FirstController

```
$data1 = reservation::select('user_id')
->where('date',request('date'))
->where('time',request('time'))
->where('room_id',request('room_id'))
->get();
```

in my >SecondController (( where I want to use the value of data1 ))

```
$msg = new message();
        $msg->date = Carbon::now();
        $msg->content = request('content');
        $msg->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $msg->reciver = $data1;     // here is where i want to use the value of $data1
```

Note: the value of $data1 changes.

**UPDATE:**
I have a form (res.blade.php) where the user inserts the data *the data I request in the first controller/date, time, room_id /*. then I redirect the user to another blade where he inserts new info (content) then I save the new data + the **$data1** I got from the first blade's inputs

Comment: You can put that in Session  for instance.

Comment: Create a BaseController with constructor, or even better: Trait. Extend BaseController or use the Trait to make use of written script.

Answer (score 0):

Create a middleware CommonData.php with below function:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
        $data1 = reservation::select('user_id')
->where('date',request('date'))
->where('time',request('time'))
->where('room_id',request('room_id'))
->get();

 $request->merge(['data1'=>$data1);
        return $next($request);
}
```

Use this in any controller like this:
$request->data1 or request('data1')

Comment: I did this, but it is not working it is adding  : ' [] ' to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a global middleware with name like Data1Middleware.php:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   $data1 = reservation::select('user_id')
        ->where('date',request('date'))
        ->where('time',request('time'))
        ->where('room_id',request('room_id'))
        ->get();

   $request->request->add(['data1', $data1]);

   return $next($request);
}
```

and add to $middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php as [resource](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#global-middleware).

```
protected middleware = [
 'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
 'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
 'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
 'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
 'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
 'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
 //....
 \App\Http\Middleware\Data1Middleware::class,
]
```

**EDITED:**

if "reservation" is your model, maybe it must be CamelCase (eg: Reservation) and in top of the middleware file add this:

```
<?php
//....
use App\Models\Reservation;
//....

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   $data1 = Reservation::select('user_id')
        ->where('date',request('date'))
        ->where('time',request('time'))
        ->where('room_id',request('room_id'))
        ->get();

   $request->request->add(['data1', $data1]);

   return $next($request);
}
```

but if "reservation" is the database table name, so you can fetch data with query builder:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   $data1 = DB::table('reservation')::select('user_id')
        ->where('date',request('date'))
        ->where('time',request('time'))
        ->where('room_id',request('room_id'))
        ->get();

   $request->request->add(['data1', $data1]);

   return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I GET : ntegrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'reciver' cannot be null 
i am calling it like this :         $msg->reciver = request('data1');

Comment: I tried to change $data1 from $data1=reservation:: ... etc, to $data1 = '20' (just to know where is the problem) and it worked and added the 20 in the database, so I think the way I am forming $data1 is wrong, do you have any suggestions, please?

Comment: @kylie I updated the answer, you can test it.

Comment: Yes, reservation is the Model. 
still getting the Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'reciver' cannot be null error Sir.

Comment: please change "reservation" to "Reservation". (in all places: name of Model class, model class file , ....). and so temporarily change to $data1 = Reservation::get(); if you receive null again, so you dont have any data in database table! otherwise go over and complete the query step by step to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve this using a [PHP Trait](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

### Create a Trait

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Traits;

use App\Models\Reservation;

trait HasReservationData
{

     public function reservationData()
    {
         // Better keep the model name start's with capital letter i.e. Pascal Case
        return Reservation::select('user_id')
            ->where('date',request('date'))
            ->where('time',request('time'))
            ->where('room_id',request('room_id'))
            ->get();
    }

}
```

#### Now let's use the Trait for our Controllers that need the reservation data.

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Http\Controllers\StackOverFlow;

use App\Traits\HasReservationData;

class FirstController
{

    use HasReservationData;

    public function someMethod()
    {
        // You have the data here and manipulate the data however you want
        $data =  $this->reservationData();

        $msg = new Message();
        $msg->date = now();
        $msg->content = request('content');
        $msg->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $msg->reciver = $data;
    }

}
```

#### Maybe another controller

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Http\Controllers\StackOverFlow;

use App\Traits\HasReservationData;

class SecondController
{

    use HasReservationData;

    public function someMethod()
    {
        // You have the data here and manipulate the data however you want
        $data =  $this->reservationData();
    }

}
```

Comment: it is not recognizing the $data1 variable Sir